# when I trying to use port 3000 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS it showing error Error: bind EACCES

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, port, bind

```
development: {
    appHost: "localhost",
    root: rootPath,
    app: {
      name: 'XXXXXXX'
    },
    port: 3000,
    securePort :443,
    db: 'mongodb'
   }  

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app),
      httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpsServer.listen(config.securePort);

httpServer.listen(config.port);
```

Comment: You need to be root/admin to open a privileged port (less than 1024).

Comment: this can also happen if you are running another instance of the server in a different terminal window/shell

Comment: Instead of binding to two separate ports you should bind to a single port and use a separate server (apache, nginx, antyhing you want) that binds to port 443 and uses SSL termination.  You can also redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS at the proxy level so you don't have to worry about this at all with node.

Comment: Thanks, But if use securePort : 3001 (>1024) the it working fine on same server (using express).

Comment: @Born2Code No it can't. That gives a different error.

Comment: @Pravin That proves the point. You don't have root access so you can't use port 443.

Comment: @EJP Thats correct, I Started my server from root access and it works fine now. :)  Thanks guys... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cant use port below 1024 as user, to access port like 443 we have to start our server from root. (super user).

command :
 $ su
password: